# How does a socket event get propagated/converted to epoll?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, glibc, centos6

I am curious how epoll_wait() receives the event that a registered socket (with epoll_ctl()) is ready for read/write.

I believe that glibc magically handles it.

Then, is there a document describing how the following events can be triggered for a socket?

1. EPOLLPRI
2. EPOLLRDNORM
3. EPOLLRDBAND
4. EPOLLWRNORM
5. EPOLLWRBAND
6. EPOLLMSG
7. EPOLLERR
8. EPOLLHUP
9. EPOLLRDHUP

P.S. Originally I was trying to paste the enum EPOLL_EVENTS in sys/epoll.h on my box here; stackoverflow thinks that I don't format the code block correctly although I wrapped it with pre and then code tag, any idea?

Comment: Epoll does all the critical work in the kernel as this post explains well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383959/why-exactly-does-epoll-scale-better-than-poll ... what exactly is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour You should move your comment into an answer.

Comment: I guess it is interrupt handler: https://notes.shichao.io/lkd/ch7/

Answer (score 10):

The most glaring problem with `epoll` documentation is its failure to state in "bold caps" that `epoll` events, are, in fact, fully identical to `poll` (2) events. Indeed, on the kernel side `epoll` handles its events in terms of older `poll` event names:

```
#define POLLIN     0x0001  // EPOLLIN
#define POLLPRI    0x0002  // EPOLLPRI
#define POLLOUT    0x0004  // EPOLLOUT
#define POLLERR    0x0008  // EPOLLERR
#define POLLHUP    0x0010  // EPOLLHUP
#define POLLNVAL   0x0020  // unused in epoll
#define POLLRDNORM 0x0040  // EPOLLRDNORM
#define POLLRDBAND 0x0080  // EPOLLRDBAND
#define POLLWRNORM 0x0100  // EPOLLWRNORM
#define POLLWRBAND 0x0200  // EPOLLWRBAND
#define POLLMSG    0x0400  // EPOLLMSG
#define POLLREMOVE 0x1000  // unused in epoll
#define POLLRDHUP  0x2000  // EPOLLRDHUP
```

Then, a brief inspection of kernel source reveals that:

- `EPOLLIN` and `EPOLLRDNORM` are identical (epoll returns `EPOLLIN | EPOLLRDNORM` when data is available for reading from the file descriptor).
- `EPOLLOUT` and `EPOLLWRNORM` are identical (epoll returns `EPOLLOUT | EPOLLWRNORM` when buffer space is available for writing).
- `EPOLLRDBAND` and `EPOLLWRBAND` signal availability of the out of band data on the descriptor (on some sockets this will be the data send with `MSG_OOB` flag passed to socket).
- `EPOLLPRI` is a modifier flag and always augments some other event (such as `EPOLLERR`). It's use is subsystem dependent, as it may mean somewhat different things depending on what purpose associated file descriptor serves.
- `EPOLLMSG` appears to be unused by the kernel and appears to serve no purpose.
- `EPOLLRDHUP` signals that the peer had closed its side of the channel for reading, but may still receive data (handy to establish that no more request data is coming in).
- `EPOLLHUP` signals that the peer had closed its side of the channel.

Answer (score 2):

All the critical work for `epoll` is done in the kernel, the user space API is just an interface. The previous thread on [Why exactly does ePoll scale better than Poll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383959/why-exactly-does-epoll-scale-better-than-poll) covers the details of how the kernel implements `epoll` is nice details.

As for a document describing the events and how they are triggered the [`epoll_ctl(2) man page`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/epoll_ctl.2.html) covers each event, for example:

```
EPOLLIN
          The associated file is available for read(2) operations.

EPOLLOUT
          The associated file is available for write(2) operations.
```

For a better description of `EPOLLET` you need to read the [`epoll(7) man page`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html).

This is a [complete example of how to use epoll](https://banu.com/blog/2/how-to-use-epoll-a-complete-example-in-c/).

You use `epoll_ctl` to request which events you wish to receive events `EPOLLIN` and `EPOLLET`, the code above does this:

```
event.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;
s = epoll_ctl (efd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, infd, &event);
```

Comment: My questions are that there are many other possible events (as I listed in my original questions).  However, there is no document mentioning under what situation each type of event on the socket will be propagated to epoll_wait().  Let's take an example, what happens to the socket that epoll_wait() will receive EPOLLRDNORM?

Comment: By the way, although your link doesn't answer my question, it does have a lot of good information. Thanks for sharing Shafik!

Comment: @Hei I will clarify, you use `epoll_ctl` to request which of the events you wish to receive, I will add a link to example code.

Comment: Hi Shafik, I think you misinterpreted my question.  Let's stick with what you just added. Let's say I set event.events to EPOLLIN | EPOLLET | EPOLLRDNORM.  Then, when will I receive EPOLLRDNORM? I think possible answer is: 1. never (then why? any document says so?). 2. when x happens (then any document says so?). My main question is that there are many events specified in epoll.h, but I don't see any document talking about some of those I listed in my original question.

Comment: @Hei I had several references, I thought the one I linked covered all of them but this one does except one it looks like: http://turing.com.br/pydoc/2.7/library/select.html let me see if I can dig up a better one