# Are poll and epoll event flags compatible?

Tags: c, linux, libusb, epoll

I'm trying to get libusb to work with `epoll` instead of `poll`, as I'm already using epoll in an application that needs scalability and will only be running on Linux. I'm wondering if the `events` flags returned by `libusb_get_pollfds`, which are intended for poll, are compatible with epoll.

Can the `POLLIN` flag, for example, be registered with `epoll` and achieve the same behavior as the `EPOLLIN` flag, or do I need to map these event flags to their corresponding epoll version?

Comment: Do you anticipate having 10000 usb devices connected? Otherwise this is utterly pointless, gratuitous introduction of a non-portable interface in place of a more portable one.

Comment: I'm using epoll for more than just usb in this application, and scalability is of concern. Linux is the only target platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can the `POLLIN` flag, for example, be registered with `epoll` and
>   achieve the same behavior as the `EPOLLIN` flag, or do I need to map
>   these event flags to their corresponding epoll version?

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27143672/2413201) is telling. Excerpt:

> The most glaring problem with `epoll` documentation is its failure to
>   state in "bold caps" that `epoll` events, are, in fact, fully
>   identical to `poll` (2) events.