# epoll vs select for very small number of connections

Tags: c++, networking, select, cpu-usage, epoll

I have been using select to handle connections, recently there was a change an our socket library and select was replaced by epoll for linux platform.

my application architecture is such that I make only one or at max 2 socket connections and epoll/select on them in a single thread.

now with recent switch to epoll i noticed that performance of application has diminshed, I was actually surprised and was expecting performance go up or reamin same. I tried looking at various other parts and this is the only peice of code that has changed.

does epoll have performance penalty in terms of speed if used for very small number of sockets (like 1 or 2).

also anoher thing to note that I run around 125 such processes on same box (8 cpu cores).
could this be case that too many processes doing epoll_wait on same machine, this setup was similar when i was using select.

i noticed on box that load average is much higher but cpu usage was quite the same which makes me think that more time is spend in I/O and probaly coming from epoll related changes.

any ideas/pointers on what should i look more to identify the problem.

although absolute latency increased is quite small like average 1 millisec but this is a realtime system and this kind of latencies are generally unaccpetable.

Thanks

Hi,

Updating this question on latest findinds, apart from switching from select to epoll I found another relate change, earlier timeout with select was 10 millis but with epoll the way timeout is way smaller than before (like 1 micro..), can setting too low timeout in select or epoll result on decreased performance in anyway?

thanks

Comment: Related question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093185/whats-the-difference-between-epoll-poll-threadpool

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any benefit to using epoll with a very small number of file descriptors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597452/is-there-any-benefit-to-using-epoll-with-a-very-small-number-of-file-descriptors)

Answer (score 3):

From the sounds of it, throughput may be unaffected with `epoll()` vs `select()`, but you're finding extra latency in individual requests that seems to be related to the use of `epoll()`.

I think that in the case of watching only one or two sockets, `epoll()` should perform much like `select()`.  `epoll()` is supposed to scale linearly as you watch more descriptors, whereas `select()` scales badly (& may even have a hard limit on #/descriptors).  So it's not that `epoll()` has a penalty for a small # of descriptors, but it loses its performance advantage over `select()` in this case.

Can you change the code so you can easily go back & forth between the two event notification mechanisms?  Get more data about the performance difference.  If you conclusively find that `select()` has less latency & same throughput in your situation, then I'd just switch back to the "old & deprecated" API without hesitation :)  To me it's fairly conclusive if you measure a performance difference from this specific code change.  Perhaps previous testing of `epoll()` versus `select()` has focused on throughput versus latency of individual requests?